# Integration with Dirac-Delta and Exponential

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I've been trying to determine the integral $$\int_{0}^{\tau_2} \delta(\tau_1)e^{\tau_1a_2} \;\mathrm{d}\tau_1$$

By the sifting property, I would assume the answer to be $1$.

However, when using MATLAB's integral calculator this gives a value $\frac{sgn(\tau_1)}{2}$. To further confuse matters, WolframAlpha's online integral calculator gives $H(\tau_1)$, where $H$ is the Heaviside step function.

Which of these is correct? And why are the three methods giving different results? If anyone can shed light on this problem, that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that $\delta(\tau_1)$ has its support on the boundary of the interval of integration. The question then arrises whether it should be considered to belong to the interval or not, or perhaps let half of it belong to the interval.

Comment: Yep, spot on, this answers my question! A massive lapse in my judgement. Thank you for your help.